# Is LUKS/cryptsetup's `hddname` (or `name`) simply an arbitrary label used during the session

Tags: encryption, luks

This is a very simple question about LUKS encryption.

My Fedora 15 system uses LUKS over the root, home and swap LVM partitions. To access these partitions from a boot cd, for example, its [necessary](http://www.forwestmedia.com/resources/how-to-guides/luks-encryption/) to open LUKS with the command,

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/<drive> <hddname>
```

Can this `hddname` be anything? More specifically, when I look at the output of the command `lsblk -a` my install has no labels.

Another tutorial listed the `hddname` as `cryptroot`, and I've been able to open LUKS with this name. Only I get the impression this is arbitrary.

I'm having trouble with mounting an encrypted [LVM partition](https://superuser.com/questions/436533/why-does-lvm-hdd-fail-mount-command-when-booting-from-cdrom/436689#comment504250_436689) and I'm confused about the vocabulary 'name space', so to speak, of LUKS and LVM.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any `hddname` you want, as long as it is not already used.

The cryptsetup manpage says about `luksOpen <device> <name>`:

> opens the LUKS partition `<device>` and sets up a mapping `<name>` after successful verification of the supplied key material

You can check currently used mappings with `ls -al /dev/mapper/`. Additionally, `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`, and `lvdisplay` can provide useful information.

---

#### Short guide to mount encrypted logical volumes

If you created a logical volume *on top* of dm-crypt:

1. `cryptsetup luksOpen <encrypted_device> <any_name>`
2. `vgchange -ay`
3. `mount /dev/mapper/<logical_volume> <mount_target>`

Step 2 enables all available logical volumes and may be omitted.

If you used dm-crypt *on top* of a logical volume:

1. `vgchange -ay`
2. `cryptsetup luksOpen <encrypted_logical_volume> <any_name>`
3. `mount /dev/mapper/<any_name> <target>`